# After rebooting nodes, pods stuck in containerCreating state due to insufficient weave IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, weave, cni

I have 3 node Kubernetes cluster on 1.11 deployed with kubeadm and weave(CNI) running of version 2.5.1. I am providing weave CIDR of IP range of 128 IP's. After two reboot of nodes some of the pods stuck in `containerCreating` state.

Once you run `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` you will see following errors:

```
Events:
Type     Reason                  Age                From                Message
----     ------                  ----               ----                
-------
Normal   SandboxChanged          20m (x20 over 1h)  kubelet, 10.0.1.63  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  30s (x25 over 1h)  kubelet, 10.0.1.63  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

If I check how many containers are running and how many IP address are allocated to those, I can see 24 containers:

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-63 centos]# weave ps | wc -l
26
```

The number of total IP's to weave at that node is 42.

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-212 centos]# kubectl exec -n kube-system -it weave-net-6x4cp -- /home/weave/weave --local status ipam
Defaulting container name to weave.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/weave-net-6x4cp -n kube-system' to see all of the containers in this pod.
6e:0d:f3:d7:f5:49(10.0.1.63)                42 IPs (32.8% of total) (42 active)
7a:24:6f:3c:1b:be(10.0.1.212)               40 IPs (31.2% of total) 
ee:00:d4:9f:9d:79(10.0.1.43)                46 IPs (35.9% of total)
```

You can see all 42 IP's are active so no more IP's are available to allocate to new containers. But out of 42 only 26 are actually allocated to containers, I am not sure where are remaining IP's. It is happening on all three nodes.

Here is the output of weave status for your reference:

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-212 centos]# weave status

    Version: 2.5.1 (version 2.5.2 available - please upgrade!)

    Service: router
    Protocol: weave 1..2
       Name: 7a:24:6f:3c:1b:be(10.0.1.212)
    Encryption: disabled
PeerDiscovery: enabled
    Targets: 3
Connections: 3 (2 established, 1 failed)
      Peers: 3 (with 6 established connections)
TrustedSubnets: none

    Service: ipam
     Status: waiting for IP(s) to become available
      Range: 192.168.13.0/25
DefaultSubnet: 192.168.13.0/25
```

If you need anymore information, I would happy to provide. Any Clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if you're weave IP's are exhausted and some of the IP's are not released after reboot. You can delete the file `/var/lib/weave/weave-netdata.db` and restart the weave pods.

For my case, I have added a systemd script which on every reboot or shutdown of the system removes the `/var/lib/weave/weave-netdata.db` file and Once system comes up it allocates new Ip's to all the pods and the weave IP exhaust were never seen again.

Posting this here in hope someone else will find it useful for their use case.

Comment: hacks are needed but we should be opening Github issues.

Comment: Yes at that time we had only limited number of IPs (256 to be exact) and weave needs sometime to recover the IP's and hence we had to implement this workaround. We had raised an issue at that time and they have asked us to increase IP range to avoid this scenario. This issue was happening when we continuously reboot our environment causing pods to be rebooted again and again in our stress testing.

Comment: Ok, we face this issue when there were lot of scale up and down happening and i think it could be related to dead nodes lying in the cluster and IPAM not becoming ready. Have opened a issue https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/3767

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if we have the same problem.
But before i reboot a node. I need to `drain` it first. So, all pods in that nodes will be evicted. We are safe to reboot the node.
After that node is up. You need to `uncordon` again. The node will be available to scheduling pod again.

My reference https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/

Comment: That is the safe way to reboot a node. In our case, K8s is in baremetal environment and it can happen that a node can go down due to network failure or some other reason.

Comment: Yes, my k8s environment is in baremetal too. But i'm using Calico for the CNI. However, if you did the safe way to reboot that node. It should be sync. And that error show us that new pod is not signed by weave. I am not sure how Weave works. According to the reference https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/3384#issuecomment-415487094

Answer (score 1):

I guess that 16 IP's have reserved for Pods reuse purpose. These are the maximum pods per node based on CIDR ranges.

```
  Maximum Pods per Node CIDR Range per Node
  8                     /28
  9 to 16               /27
  17 to 32              /26
  33 to 64              /25
  65 to 110             /24
```